# How do I print in index of my output for a numpy arange?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

```
def x(t,A,ω,γ,ϕ):
    return A*np.cos(np.sqrt(ω**2-(γ/2)**2)*t+ϕ)*np.exp(-γ*t/2)

a=x(np.arange(0,10,0.01),1,1,1,-np.pi/2)

b=[np.max(np.abs(a)), ]

print(b)

#This was the output [0.47310347814336845]
```

I want to know how can I get the index of the np.arange that this output belongs to?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.argmax()`:

```py
np.argmax(np.abs(a))
```

This outputs:

```py
121
```